# Getting all ViewBag into Array List and Set to Null

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to construct this simple Foreach loop:

```
public void SetCurrent(ControllerBase controllerBase)
{
    System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider iv = null;
    ControllerBase[] ctrlbase = { ViewBag.samplea, ViewBag.sampleb};

    foreach (var ct in ctrlbase)
    {
        ct.ValueProvider = iv;
    }

    controllerBase.Equals("current");
}
```

But when i tried to run the code it returns me an error to this portion `ct.ValueProvider = iv;`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is how i test the function:

```
SetCurrent(ViewBag.samplea);
```

What i'm trying to do is Set all `ViewBag to Empty String` or `null` and set the parameter to value to `current` which it's look something like `controllerBase="current"`.

Is it possible using this simple function?

Any Bright Ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I need to set all Viewbag to empty string not include the parameter. I tried a  lot of attemp but got no lucky.

Comment: Try doing `ViewData.Clear();` instead of creating `ControllerBase[]` and looping

Comment: Thanks even `ViewData.Clear()` is working how about the parameter to set to `current`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a temporary solution that iv'e made:

```
public void SetCurrent(String Controlbase)
        {
            SetAllViewBagToNull();
            switch (Controlbase)
            {
                case "samplea":
                    {
                        ViewBag.samplea= "current";
                        break;
                    }
                case "sampleb":
                    {
                        ViewBag.sampleb= "current";
                        break;
                    }
            }


        }
        public void SetAllViewBagToNull()
        { 
            ViewBag.samplea= "";
            ViewBag.sampleb= "";
        }
```

Off course its `working` because as we observed this is a `manual` coding.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you want to clear the `ViewBag`, we can call

```
ViewData.Clear();
```

`ViewBag` is just a [wrapper](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs) around the `ViewData`.

2) If you want to remove specific items, you can always do it manually:

```
ViewBag.sampleb = null;
```

Update:

3) If you are getting the `key` value in `Controlbase` parameter, you can do this:

```
public void SetCurrent(String Controlbase)
{
    SetAllViewBagToNull();
    ViewData[Controlbase] = "current";
}
```

Comment: Thanks how about it i set the parameter value to current like the sample above. Accepted your idea.

Comment: `ViewData[Controlbase] = "current";` has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @reds is `Controlbase` parameter a string?

Comment: No it's ViewBag like `ViewBag.samplea`

Comment: Take a look at my Answer below.. as iv'e said it's working but the i'm hoping any solution from my question from above.

Comment: `ViewData` is not all about `ViewBag`.. ViewData is in `Model` Part

Comment: @reds I have updated the answer according to your answer.

Comment: Parameter is like from my sample above `ControllerBase controllerBase` and its not a string. but anyway thanks.

Comment: @reds You need to add the code from where and why you're calling this. It's not clear at the moment.